# AWS multiple domains point to single EC2 Linux instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-route53

Is it possible to setup multiple domains to point with one single linux ec2 instance?

For example : 
I have registered following 3 domain and I need to point to below path in single Linux EC2 instance:
www.domain1.com - var/www/html/domain1

www.domain2.com - var/www/html/domain2

www.domain3.com - var/www/html/domain3

Answer (score 5):

Very much possible. You can add A records in the dns zone of your domain registrar pointing to the elastic ip of your ec2 instance to get the requests routed.If you are having public dns instead of an elastic ip, you can add CNAME record instead of A record

Further you can use apache inside your ec2 to route the requests as you wish to required application path. Steps below. *(This assumes that you have the document roots to be served for the 3 domains copied to the respective paths mentioned in your question)*

**Step 1 :** Configure your second and 3rd domains also to point to the same EC2 public IP using domain registrar (go daddy in your case) DNS Zones configuration.  *(Assuming all 3 domains are yet to go live)*

**Step 2 :** Create virtual hosts file for the 3 domains which you want. Content given below.

File 1: /etc/httpd/conf.d/domain1.com.conf with content

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName www.domain1.com
  ServerAlias domain1.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1
  ErrorLog /var/www/html/www.domain1.com/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/www.domain1.com/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

File 2: /etc/httpd/conf.d/domain2.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName www.domain2.com
  ServerAlias domain2.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2
  ErrorLog /var/www/html/www.domain2.com/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/www.domain2.com/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

File 3: /etc/httpd/conf.d/domain3.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName www.domain3.com
  ServerAlias domain3.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain3
  ErrorLog /var/www/html/www.domain3.com/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/www.domain3.com/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Once this is done, you can restart apache and check.

Hope this helps

*Note: In case this is not working for you or if you are facing some errors, please do include the apache version, OS and version as well in the response :)*

Comment: Thanks for reply
Could you please explain the steps to follow. Currently i have registered my domains in Godaddy and i pointed one domain to ec2 instance.by giving ec2 ip in godaddy dns record type A. Then What i need to do , to point for second domain

Comment: Can you help some more information so that I can help you with the steps. The apache instance which you ate using is having this specific application alone or any ither applications in it?

Comment: I have updated the answer with some more steps. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is like normal Linux server. You can use as many domains as you want. Just point all of them to the IP address of the instance (recommending using Elastic IP). A record is better as it is faster to translate.

Then it is upon Apache Server, it controlls what directory to use with each domain.

Comment: Thanks for reply . 
Could you please explain the steps to follow. Currently i have registered my domains in Godaddy and i pointed one domain to ec2 instance.by giving ec2 ip in godaddy dns record type A. Then What i need to do , to point for second domain